# popup contains whole page

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem in my website
I added a new popup but somehow it doesnt work properly I used this link
http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/pure-css-popup-without-javascript/
and on my website it floats over content and other content is still visible somehow, please have a look at www.kareem-helal.com/metin and press on Inregistrare and see what happens 
you can check the code by view page source or here's a small part

```
<li><a id="a2" href="#popup1">ÎNREGISTRARE</a></li>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thanks for pop me out of that button, but now I'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

I don't really know the problem can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

add z-index to `.overlay` class

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:9999;/*Add this property*/
}
```

replace your html like

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="">
            Thanks for pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great it works but why height is so big not as the snippet?

Comment: effect this class .content {
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 505px;
}

Comment: remove this class ".content"

Comment: .popup .content? when i remove it nothing happens